# Reaction Collector Discordjs

Tags: node.js, discord.js, bots

My reaction collector seems to not work properly. I dont know why. I tried a few different versions but nothing seem to help. Here is the code of my Command. The idea behind it is to do the command, then the bot sends an embed with the reaction. When a user reacts to it they should get the "Member" role.

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('rules')
        .setDescription("the Rules of the Server")
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers)
        .setDMPermission(false),


    async execute(interaction) {
        const ruleChannel = "1090705828304146544"
        const memberRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member')

        let embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('Rules')
            .setDescription('Rule 1: bla bla \nRule 2: bla bla')

        const messageEmbed = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], fetchReply: true })
        messageEmbed.react('✅')

        const collectorFilter = (reaction, user) => {
            return reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && !user.bot;
        };

        const collector = messageEmbed.createReactionCollector({ filter: collectorFilter})

        collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            if(reaction.emoji.name === '✅'){
                user.roles.add(memberRole)
            }     
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: The Collector doesnt do anything. I've tried to test it with `console.log()` but it didnt show anything

Comment: i just added the imports. maybe something is there wrong

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are 2 errors in your code.

1. `.add(memberRole)` => `.add(memberRole.id)`
2. `user.roles.add` A role cannot be given to user, a role is given to "member".

Here is the working code:

````js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('@discordjs/builders');
const { PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js')

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('rules')
        .setDescription("the Rules of the Server")
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers)
        .setDMPermission(false),


    async execute(interaction) {
        const ruleChannel = "1090705828304146544"
        const memberRole = interaction.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === 'Member')

        let embed = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('Rules')
            .setDescription('Rule 1: bla bla \nRule 2: bla bla')

        const messageEmbed = await interaction.reply({ embeds: [embed], fetchReply: true })
        messageEmbed.react('✅')

        const collectorFilter = (reaction, user) => {
            return reaction.emoji.name === '✅' && !user.bot;
        };

        const collector = messageEmbed.createReactionCollector({ filter: collectorFilter})

        collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
            if(reaction.emoji.name === '✅'){
              interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(memberRole.id)
            }     
        })
    }
}```
````

Comment: still not working. I put some `console.log`'s in there and none of the are being displayed. So the problem has to do something with "collecting" the interaction.

Comment: i now tried to use the `collector.on('end)` function. After a timelimit, the role should get added to a member that reacted. But i only got an error message:

`interaction.guild.members.cache.get(user).roles.add(memberRole)
                                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'roles')`

Comment: You can use that part of the code I edited in your own code.